# NEST Aggregate similar to SQL Group By

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

This is my class when inserting to ES

```
public class BasicDoc
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

I managed successfully insert my document to ES using NEST. But I'm having trouble to do a aggregation. My goals is to have something similar to SQL Group By. What I did so far:

```
var response = elastic.Search<BasicDoc>(s => s
                    .Aggregations(a => a
                        .Terms("group_by_url", st => st
                            .Field(o => o.Url)
                        ))
);
```

I tried to aggregate my document based on BasicDoc.Url. Say I have these in my ES:

1. /api/call1/v1
2. /api/call2/v1
3. /api/call1/v1

When I debug, I my Nest.BucketAggregate will have 4 Items key which is ***api***,***call1***, ***call2*** and ***v1***. I was expecting only 2 which are /api/call1/v1 and /api/call2/v1. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have [analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) set up on your `Url` property which means that it will be tokenized by the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) and terms stored in the inverted index. If you need to be able to search on `Uri` **and** also need to aggregate on it, then you may consider mapping it as a [multi_field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) where one field mapping analyzes it and another does not. Here's an example index creation with mapping

```
client.CreateIndex("index-name", c => c
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<BasicDoc>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .String(s => s
                    .Name(n => n.Url)
                    .Fields(f => f
                        .String(ss => ss
                            .Name("raw")
                            .NotAnalyzed()
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

When you perform your aggregation, you can now use the `Uri` raw field

```
var response = client.Search<BasicDoc>(s => s
    .Size(0)
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("group_by_url", st => st
            .Field(o => o.Url.Suffix("raw"))
        )
    )
);
```